# Adding points to plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Here is the first 9 rows (out of 54) and the first 8 columns (out of 1003) of my dataset

```
 stream n rates     means          1         2         3         4
 1   Brooks 3   3.0 0.9629152 0.42707006 1.9353659 1.4333884 1.8566225
 2  Siouxon 3   3.0 0.5831929 0.90503736 0.2838483 0.2838483 1.0023212
 3 Speelyai 3   3.0 0.6199235 0.08554021 0.7359903 0.4841935 0.7359903
 4   Brooks 4   7.5 0.9722707 1.43338843 1.8566225 0.0000000 1.3242210
 5  Siouxon 4   7.5 0.5865031 0.50574543 0.5057454 0.2838483 0.4756304
 6 Speelyai 4   7.5 0.6118634 0.32252396 0.4343109 0.6653132 2.2294652
 7   Brooks 5  10.0 0.9637475 0.88984211 1.8566225 0.7741612 1.3242210
 8  Siouxon 5  10.0 0.5804420 0.47501800 0.7383634 0.5482181 0.6430847
 9 Speelyai 5  10.0 0.5959238 0.15079491 0.2615963 0.4738504 0.0000000
```

Here is a simple plot I have made using the values found in the `means` column for all rows with stream name Speelyai (18).

[image]

The means column is calculated by taking the mean for the entire row. Each column represents 1 simulation. So, the mean column is the mean of 1000 simulations. I would like to plot the actual simulation values on the plot as well. I think it would be informative to not only have the mean plotted (with a line) but also show the "raw" data (simulations) as points. I see that I can use the `geom_point()`, but am not sure how to get all the points for any row that has the stream name "Speelyai"

THANKS

---

[image]

As you can see, the scales are much different, which I would assume, given these points are results from simulations, or resampling the original data. But How could I overlay these points on my original image in a way that still preserves the visual content? In this image the line looks almost flat, but in my original image we can see that it fluctuates quite a bit, just on a small scale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @NickKennedy that it's a good idea reshaping your data from wide to long:

```
library(reshape)
x2<-melt(x,id=c("stream","n","rates"))
x2<-x2[which(x2$variable!="means"),] # this eliminates the entries for means
```

Now it's time to re-calculate the means:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x2)
setkey(x2,"stream")
means.sp<-x2["Speelyai",.(mean.stream=mean(value)),by=rates]
```

So now you can plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(means.sp,aes(rates,mean.stream))+geom_line()
```

Which is exactly what you had, so now let's add the points:

```
p<-p+geom_point(data=x2[x2$stream=="Speelyai",],aes(rates,value))
```

Notice that in the call to `geom_point` you need to specifically declare `data=` as you are working with a different dataset to the one you specified in the call to `ggplot`.

**========== EDIT TO ADD =============**

replying to your comments, and borrowing from the answer @akrun gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861246/how-do-i-substract-a-value-from-a-column-in-a-dataframe-with-unique-rows), you'll need to add the calculation of the error and then change the call to `geom_point`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(stream=c('Brooks', 'Siouxon', 'Speelyai'), 
      value=c(0.944062036, 0.585852702, 0.583984402), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x2$error <- x2$value-df2$value[match(x2$stream, df2$stream)]
```

And then change the call to  `geom_point`:

```
geom_point(data=x2[x2$stream=="Speelyai",],aes(rates,error))
```

Comment: Notice that even if you plot the error, the y-range will be still large enough (about 4 units) to smooth the means curve (which I understand you want to show as sharply changing), but then "you can't conceal the facts" ;)

Comment: Yep you are right! Is is really the same range which is the issue.... AHH! I am not sure what to do....

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reformatting your data in a long format rather than wide. For example:

```
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
my_data_tidy <- gather(my_data, column, value, -c(stream, n, rates, means))
ggplot(subset(my_data_tidy, stream == "Speelyai"), aes(rates, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line")
```

Note this will also recalculate the means from your data. If you wanted to use your existing means, you could do:

```
ggplot(subset(my_data_tidy, stream == "Speelyai"), aes(rates, value)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line(aes(rates, means), data = subset(my_data, stream == "Speelyai"))
```

Comment: I see. I suppose your first ggplot code where it calculates the means is not a big deal, it should still come up with the same value. The image that is produced, looks MUCH different that the image I originally posted. I am not sure how to add that image to this comment to show you.

Comment: Different how? It's hard to check without seeing your full data, though you will now have 18000 points plotted. You might need to play with `alpha` to make the plot usable.