# How do I substract a value from a column in a dataframe, with unique rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Hard to explain the question in a title. But here I have a data frame, and you can see I have 3 stream names. I have a 3 unique values associated with each stream name. I would like these unique values to be subtracted from the value for the corresponding stream found in the `value` column and then appended to the data frame in a new column titled `error`

```
    stream  n  rates   means     column     value
1    Brooks 3   3.0  0.9629152      1    0.42707006
2   Siouxon 3   3.0  0.5831929      1    0.90503736
3  Speelyai 3   3.0  0.6199235      1    0.08554021
4    Brooks 4   7.5  0.9722707      1    1.43338843
5   Siouxon 4   7.5  0.5865031      1    0.50574543
6  Speelyai 4   7.5  0.6118634      1    0.32252396
7    Brooks 5  10.0  0.9637475      1    0.88984211
8   Siouxon 5  10.0  0.5804420      1    0.47501800
9  Speelyai 5  10.0  0.5959238      1    0.15079491
10   Brooks 6  13.0  0.9486575      1    1.32422105
11  Siouxon 6  13.0  0.5846854      1    0.39479684
12 Speelyai 6  13.0  0.5597146      1    0.37005941
```

Here are the "unique" values I want subtracted from the `value` column

```
> true.lwd.sp <- 0.583984402 (speelyai)
> true.lwd.sx <- 0.585852702 (souixon)
> true.lwd.br <- 0.944062036 (brooks)
```

Thanks for any help. One day I may know how to do all these simple tasks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could create a new dataset and match the 'stream' column with the corresponding column in the new dataset, get the numeric index to get corresponding 'value' from 'df2', and subtract from the 'df1' or original dataset.

```
 df1$error <- df1$value-df2$value[match(df1$stream, df2$stream)]
 df1
 #    stream n rates     means column      value       error
 #1    Brooks 3   3.0 0.9629152      1 0.42707006 -0.51699198
 #2   Siouxon 3   3.0 0.5831929      1 0.90503736  0.31918466
 #3  Speelyai 3   3.0 0.6199235      1 0.08554021 -0.49844419
 #4    Brooks 4   7.5 0.9722707      1 1.43338843  0.48932639
 #5   Siouxon 4   7.5 0.5865031      1 0.50574543 -0.08010727
 #6  Speelyai 4   7.5 0.6118634      1 0.32252396 -0.26146044
 #7    Brooks 5  10.0 0.9637475      1 0.88984211 -0.05421993
 #8   Siouxon 5  10.0 0.5804420      1 0.47501800 -0.11083470
 #9  Speelyai 5  10.0 0.5959238      1 0.15079491 -0.43318949
 #10   Brooks 6  13.0 0.9486575      1 1.32422105  0.38015901
 #11  Siouxon 6  13.0 0.5846854      1 0.39479684 -0.19105586
 #12 Speelyai 6  13.0 0.5597146      1 0.37005941 -0.21392499
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(stream = c("Brooks", "Siouxon", "Speelyai", 
 "Brooks", 
 "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", 
 "Siouxon", "Speelyai"), n = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), rates = c(3, 3, 3, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 10, 
 13, 13, 13), means = c(0.9629152, 0.5831929, 0.6199235, 0.9722707, 
 0.5865031, 0.6118634, 0.9637475, 0.580442, 0.5959238, 0.9486575, 
 0.5846854, 0.5597146), column = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), value = c(0.42707006, 0.90503736, 0.08554021, 
 1.43338843, 0.50574543, 0.32252396, 0.88984211, 0.475018, 0.15079491, 
 1.32422105, 0.39479684, 0.37005941)), .Names = c("stream", "n", 
 "rates", "means", "column", "value"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))

 df2 <- data.frame(stream=c('Brooks', 'Siouxon', 'Speelyai'), 
      value=c(0.944062036, 0.585852702, 0.583984402), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: But, how can I add these values back to the data frame. They would need to be in the correct row as well....

Comment: @Christopher Did you try the suggested answer to see what happens?

Comment: @A.Webb, yep and it looks like it works, my console gets bombarded with a bunch of values (resulting from the calculation performed) but when I view the data frame, these values are not there.

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `data.table` *using `df2` from @akrun's answer*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[stream == df2$stream, error := value - df2$value]

 #    stream n rates     means column      value       error
 #1:   Brooks 3   3.0 0.9629152      1 0.42707006 -0.51699198
 #2:  Siouxon 3   3.0 0.5831929      1 0.90503736  0.31918466
 #3: Speelyai 3   3.0 0.6199235      1 0.08554021 -0.49844419
 #4:   Brooks 4   7.5 0.9722707      1 1.43338843  0.48932639
 #5:  Siouxon 4   7.5 0.5865031      1 0.50574543 -0.08010727
 #6: Speelyai 4   7.5 0.6118634      1 0.32252396 -0.26146044
 #7:   Brooks 5  10.0 0.9637475      1 0.88984211 -0.05421993
 #8:  Siouxon 5  10.0 0.5804420      1 0.47501800 -0.11083470
 #9: Speelyai 5  10.0 0.5959238      1 0.15079491 -0.43318949
#10:   Brooks 6  13.0 0.9486575      1 1.32422105  0.38015901
#11:  Siouxon 6  13.0 0.5846854      1 0.39479684 -0.19105586
#12: Speelyai 6  13.0 0.5597146      1 0.37005941 -0.21392499
```

Comment: Can you try with the `setkey` join approach.  It may be faster

Comment: How does one interpret the benchmark? It did not take 30.686 minutes to run akruns expression.

Comment: @Christopher its the estimation by `microbenchmark`. To know more check `?microbenchmark`

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but `match` is very fast.  Perhaps `==` may be slower.

Comment: @Arun OK will check with larger data thanks anyways! I removed the benchmarks :)

Answer (score 1):

Akrun is right, but you need some extra code to join the datasets.
Check this simple (but similar example):

```
    library(dplyr)

  # your original dataset
    dt1 = data.frame(stream = c("A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                     value = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))

  # your dataset with the values for each case
    dt2 = data.frame(stream = c("A","B","C"),
                     truevalue = c(0.58, 0.57, 0.56))

  # join datasets and create the error variable
    result = dt1 %>% left_join(dt2, by="stream") %>% mutate(error = value - truevalue)

    result
```

The important thing is to make sure the names of the streams match in both datasets, so the join will be executed correctly.